# WHERE clause not working mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a row `Brand New` in column `condition` and when I do a query like the below it doesn't return anything,

```
SELECT * FROM table where condition LIKE '%new%'
```

but  if I do like this I get that row

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition LIKE '%Brand New%'
```

what am I missing here?

The collation for column `conditon` is `latin1_swedish_ci`

Comment: Propably your column has a case sensitive `ci` charset? Can you tell us which charset you're using for the column where the value `Brand new` is in?

Comment: You should post your table contens here, but it could be case sensitivity.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER the collation is `latin1_swedish_ci`

Comment: Sorry I wrote case sensitive `ci` I mean case sensitive `cs`. `ci` is for case insentitive and your column seems to be it (ci at the end). So that could not be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table where LOWER(`condition`) LIKE LOWER('%new%');
```

You most likely have a case sensitive setting.

This will convert both strings to lower case before comparing them.

<kbd>[Reference page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks this works, but does it depend on the collation of the column? I have `latin1_swedish_ci`.

Comment: No, it does not depend on the collation.

Comment: Try also doing:  `LIKE '%new%'" COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;` to see if the problem is in your '%new%' string.

Answer (score 0):

This will resolve the problem :

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE `condition` LIKE '%new%'"
```

Comment: Can you post the database structure and rows data?